# How to compare current value of a column with the previous value of the same column in both sql server and Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012

I have to compare the current value of a column with the previous value of the same column.
My condition says something like this:
If T1.C1 = prev T1.C1 and T1.C2 = prev T1.C2 and T1.C3 = 'somw value' then display T1.C3 as (prevT1.C3 +1)
Can someone please let me know how can I achieve this in both sql server and oracle

Answer (score 1):

It is the **`LAG`** analytic function. For example (based on Oracle, Scott's sample schema; I believe MS SQL Server works just like that, possibly with slight differences in syntax). Note line number 5.

```
SQL> WITH temp
  2       AS (SELECT empno,
  3                  ename,
  4                  sal,
  5                  LAG (sal) OVER (ORDER BY empno) prev_sal
  6             FROM emp)
  7    SELECT ename,
  8           sal,
  9           prev_sal,
 10           --
 11           CASE
 12              WHEN sal > prev_sal THEN 'higher'
 13              WHEN sal < prev_sal THEN 'lower'
 14              ELSE 'equal'
 15           END
 16              "sal compared to previous sal"
 17      FROM temp
 18  ORDER BY empno;

ENAME             SAL   PREV_SAL sal compared to previous sal
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
SMITH             920            equal
ALLEN            1600        920 higher
WARD             1250       1600 lower
JONES            2975       1250 higher
MARTIN           1250       2975 lower
BLAKE            2850       1250 higher
CLARK            2450       2850 lower
SCOTT            3000       2450 higher
KING            10000       3000 higher
TURNER           1500      10000 lower
ADAMS            1100       1500 lower
JAMES             950       1100 lower
FORD             3000        950 higher
MILLER           1300       3000 lower

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I got to understand about the use of Lag. But for my condition more than the Lag function, the Row_number() function helped. Maybe my question should have been a little different. Anyways I shall post the answer which worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WITH CUR_VAL AS
(SELECT C1,C2,C3,..,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1) RK FROM T1) 
,PREV_VAL AS
(SELECT C1,C2,C3,...,,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1)+1 RK1 FROM T1)
SELECT A.C1, B.C1 PREV_C1, B.RK1,
FROM CUR_VAL A, PREV_VAL B
WHERE A.RK = B.RK1
ORDER BY RK1